A partially ordered set has all suprema iff it has all infima
Let $(P, \leq)$ be a partially ordered set. We will show that every nonempty set bounded above in $P$ has a supremum iff every nonempty set bounded below in $P$ has an infimum. Obviously, it suffices to prove one of the directions.
Assume that every nonempty set bounded above has a supremum. Let $M \subseteq P$ be nonempty and bounded below. We will show that $M$ has an infimum. Let $N = \{a \in P \mid a \leq M\} = \{a \in P \mid \forall b \in M : a \leq b\}$ be the set of lower bounds of $M$. Since $M$ is nonempty, there is $m \in M$. Hence, we have $\forall a \in N: a \leq m$, hence $N \leq m$, so $m$ is an upper bound for $N$. Also, $M$ is bounded below, hence there exists $n \in P$ with $n \leq M$, so $n \in N$ and $N$ is nonempty. So $N$ is nonempty and bounded above, so by assumption, it has a supremum in $P$. Let $s = \operatorname{sup} N$. We will show that $s$ is a lower bound for $M$ and that is larger than all other lower bounds of $M$, thus establishing that $s$ is the infimum of $M$.
To show that $s$ is a lower bound for $M$, take any $b \in M$. Then, since $b$ is an upper bound for $N$ and $s = \operatorname{sup} N$, we have that $s \leq b$. Therefore, $s$ is a lower bound for $M$.
To show that $s$ is larger than all other lower bounds of $M$, let $t$ be another lower bound of $M$, meaning that $t \leq M$. This implies that $t \in N$ and due to $s = \operatorname{sup} N$, we have $s \geq t$. Therefore, $s$ is larger than all other lower bounds of $M$.
In total, $s$ is a lower bound for $M$, and it is larger than all other lower bounds for $M$, so we have $s = \operatorname{inf} M$.
Is this proof correct? Does it hold for more general order relations than just partial orderings?

The proof is correct, but to my taste it would be nicer to not have to argue by contradiction, giving instead a direct proof, which is possible. The fact holds true for general posets (you don't need to assume that any two elements are comparable).

@user43208 I think the proof by contradiction only works if we assume that the order is total, so I will try to carry out the proof directly and see whether we need that assumption.

Looks good, +1. A careful examination of the definitions shows that you don't really need the antisymmetry axiom for posets (discarding that condition, you get the notion of preorder). It might be possible to generalize beyond preorders, but it wouldn't be very "natural", I don't think.

This is all well-known, but I wanted to write it out to make manifest where the axioms of a poset come into play, at least according to one definitional set-up. The least important axiom here is antisymmetry (if $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$, then $x = y$). Its only role is to ensure uniqueness of suprema/infima where they exist; at the slight cost of replacing definite articles ("the") with indefinite articles, it may be discarded.
I also wanted to write out a proof of a slightly modified statement that eliminates all the fuss of having to work with nonempty subsets throughout.
Definition: For a poset $P$ and subset $A \subseteq P$, an element $x$ is the supremum of $A$ if for every $y \in P$,
$$(\forall a \in A) (a \leq y) \Leftrightarrow x \leq y.$$
By taking $y = x$ and applying reflexivity, the direction $\Leftarrow$ implies that $x$ is an upper bound of $A$. The direction $\Rightarrow$ shows that it is least among the upper bounds. It may be shown, using the antisymmetry axiom, that the supremum of a subset is unique if it exists.
An element $x$ is the infimum of $B \subseteq P$ if for every $y \in P$,
$$(\forall b \in B)(y \leq b) \Leftrightarrow y \leq x.$$
Arguing similarly to the above, the infimum of $B$ according to this definition is a lower bound of $B$, and it is the greatest among the lower bounds.
Definition: A sup-lattice is a poset $P$ such that every subset of $P$ has a least upper bound, or supremum. An inf-lattice is a poset $P$ such that every subset of $P$ has a greatest lower bound, or infimum.
Theorem: Every inf-lattice is a sup-lattice, and conversely.
Note that the opposite $P^{op}$ of a sup-lattice $P$, defined as having the same underlying set as $P$ but where $x \leq y$ in $P^{op}$ iff $y \leq x$ in $P$, is an inf-lattice. Similarly, the opposite of an inf-lattice is a sup-lattice. Thus, it suffices to prove only one direction of the theorem.
Proof: Let $(P, \leq)$ be an inf-lattice, and let $A \subseteq P$ be a subset (allowed to be empty). Claim: the infimum $x$ of the set $B$ of upper bounds of $A$ is the supremum of $A$. For, observe that for any $y \in P$
$$\begin{array}{rcll} 
(\forall a \in A)(a \leq y) & \Leftrightarrow & y \in B & \text{(definition of $B$)} \\
& \Rightarrow & x \leq y & \text{(because the infimum of $B$ is a lower bound of $B$).} 
\end{array}$$
In the other direction, supposing $x \leq y$, observe that for any $a \in A$
$$(\forall b \in B) (a \leq b),$$
whence $a \leq x$ by definition of infimum; together with $x \leq y$ this implies $a \leq y$ by transitivity. Thus we have shown
$$x \leq y \Rightarrow (\forall a \in A) (a \leq y)$$
and this completes the proof.
